Ошибка в контейнере ksql
При запуске контейнер ksql несколько раз выдаёт ошибку ниже и отключается. С чем это может быть связано?
2024-04-17 12:55:44 [2024-04-17 08:55:44,058] INFO [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1090) 2024-04-17 12:55:44 [2024-04-17 08:55:44,058] WARN [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:910)

Конфигурация:
  kafka:
image: bitnami/kafka:latest
ports:
  - '9092:9092'
environment:
  - KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT=yes
  - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=1
  - KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID=1
  - KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=1
  - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=broker,controller
  - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
  - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9094
  - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
  - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9094
  - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=1@:9093
  - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
ksql:
image: bitnami/ksql:latest
restart: always
ports:
  - "8088:8088"
environment:
  KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "localhost:9092"
  KSQL_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8088

